# JavaFX single line instance variables aren't working properly with scene builder. Any solutions?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

When initializing containers in a controller class (say an anchorpane), scenebuilder only recognizes the last instance if of the given container if the code is written like the following:

```
@FXML
private AnchorPane pane1, pane2, pane3;
```

That is, when I open scenebuilder and select a pane, the dropdown menu under fx:id only shows pane3 instead of all three.

To get scenebuilder to recognize the various containers, I seperated them all as such:

```
@FXML
private AnchorPane pane1;

@FXML
private AnchorPane pane2;

@FXML
private AnchorPane pane3;
```

I'd prefer to use the previous method for initializing because this alternative approach is producing 200+ lines of just container initialization. Is there any particular reason scenebuilder isn't recognizing then pane1 and pane2 when pane3 is the last one listed in the previous approach?

Comment: SceneBuildet has nothing to do with the code. it is an xml (fxml) file generator and nothing more. having 200 elements to initialize is most likely due to bad scene design (group common elements into separate controls).

Comment: SceneBuilder code is in [GitHub](https://github.com/gluonhq/scenebuilder), if it is not doing what you want, you could modify it, provided you have the time, skill and motivation.

Comment: @mrmcwolf Yes, but I believe Scene Builder will inspect the controller file so that it can do things like list `@FXML`-annotated fields in the `fx:id` dropdown for easier use. I think the OP's point is that Scene Builder doesn't see all the fields when they are declared in a single statement, in contrast to when the fields are declared in separate statements. If Scene Builder looks at the compiled class, I don't see why the single-statement approach would break. But I could see bugs appearing if Scene Builder parses the source code itself.

Comment: @Slaw,I see the use of SceneBuilder in the opposite direction - from FXML to generate a controller. The reverse function - to parse controllers is optional. However, this is where we start commenting on application features. They may intentionally not parse the whole line or it may just be an oversight, so this can be discussed on [github](https://github.com/gluonhq/scenebuilder/discussions)